# How to use SciType font in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

I saw a font with math support inside OTF glyphs.

How to use it (with lualatex or xelatex for example)? Especially how to deal with stylistic sets with LaTex.

Here is the link : [SciType font description](http://canadatype.net/pdf/SciType_FAQ.pdf) or for something more complete [manual](http://www.vanmaanen.org/fonts/scitype/Introduction%20SciType.pdf)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what SciType is… is it a font or is it a authoring environment?  From the description is is expressly not TeX, but assuming it's a font I'm surprised it cares.

Comment: Sylistic sets are selected with `\addfontfeature{StylisticSet=SS20}` (cf. [fontspec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)). But why would you choose type setting formulas with SciType over LaTeX *within* LaTeX?

Comment: Well the font choice is quite limited for math fonts with LaTex (even with mathdesign or such package).

Answer (score 8):

I am the developer of SciType for Canada Type. SciType offers an opportunity to get simple math and science properly typeset in text and presentation software (Word, Nisus, Keynote...). It works via the OpenType GSUB tables, and replaces e.g. `space x space` by space multiply space`and`2^2`by`two two.sups`and`\a`by`alpha`.

The last example shows that SciType will not work with LaTeX: `\a` would be a  command. Also, like DG noted, it's a bit unnecessary to use these tricks inside LaTeX: the LaTeX repertoire is vastly superior to anything an OpenType font can accomplish (double exponents, large integrals, what have you). And it doesn't work: LateX finishes typesetting `5 x 5` before OpenType can replace the x.
SciType is really just a quick fix because it drove me as a science journalist crazy not to have proper math and chem symbols ready at hand in presentations (I don't use Beamer...) and short articles. I use XeLaTex for books.
The extra glyphs in the SciType fonts are accessible via Unicode (two.sups = 00B2, alpha = 1D6FC, italic a = 1D44E etc.).

Hope this helps? Cheers, Hans